# Creating Our Own Session Handler

Tags: php, session, laravel-4

I'm trying to create my own session handler. I've found this [resource](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-unwrapped-session-auth-and-cache--cms-19952). The problem with that, is that he make changes to *vendor* directory which is something I don't want to.

The reason for that is, I'm working with others, it's a collaborative project using version control system (`push`ing the main application `ignore` the vendor folder ) and besides that I presume with each `composer install` all changes will be lost (although I'm not sure).

It crossed my mind to change the `DatabaseSessionHandler`, after all , all I wanted was to change the field names of the table that Laravel uses for storing the session (I'm working on a pre-existing database), but it would be the same as I mentioned above.

Is there any way I could create my own session handler and use it in my application?
A service provider or something even better?

Links will be appreciated.

**Update**

Something I want to clarify, I want to be able to use `Laravel`s [API](http://laravel.com/docs/session).

Another resource I've found is Laravels doc [how to write a session extension](http://laravel.com/docs/extending#session), but I think a lot of stuff is missing. It says I have to create a service provider cause sessions are started very early in the request-lifecycle. Any directions from there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It says I have to create a service provider cause sessions are started very early in the request-lifecycle. Any directions from there?

What that actually means is that you have to register a Session Service Provider in the [`IoC-Container`](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc) very early in the request-lifecycle.

Since the bindings in your `app/config/app.php` will be registered very early during the bootstrapping process of laravel, it is the perfect place to bind your custom `SessionHandler`-Extension.

Basically you need the following things to tackle your problem:

- A Service Provider that binds a new instance of a SessionHandlerInterface (your concrete Custom Session Handler) to the IoC Container
- And edit in your `app/config/app.php` that adds your new Service Provider
- Your Custom Session Handler Class

Let's get started:

**Bootstrapping the Service Provider:**

The [Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/extending#session) tell us to add our Custom Service Provider **below** the `Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider` so in your `app/config/app.php` add the following line below laravel SessionServiceProvider:

`'MyProject\Extension\CustomSessionServiceProvider',`

Now during laravels bootstrapping process out `CustomSessionServiceProvider` will be loaded right after laravels. In our custom provider we will do the actual binding.

**Creating the Service Provider:**

Now that you made sure the Service Provider is being loaded we will implement it.
Within the service provider we can overwrite the binding of laravels `DatabaseSessionHandler` which we will do.

```
<?php namespace MyProject\Extension;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Session;

class CustomSessionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $connection = $this->app['config']['session.connection'];
        $table = $this->app['config']['session.table'];

        $this->app['session']->extend('database', function($app) use ($connection, $table){
            return new \MyProject\Extension\CustomDatabaseSessionHandler(
                $this->app['db']->connection($connection),
                $table
            );
        });
    }

}
```

First we grab the connection type that we use to store our session and then the table where the sessions will be stored.

Since you only want to change column names we don't need to implement a whole new Database Session Handler. Instead let's extend Laravels `Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler` and overwrite the necessary methods.

Laravels `DatabaseSessionHandler` has two dependencies. An implementation of the `ConnectionInterface` and a table name. Both are injected into our `CustomDatabaseSessionHandler` which you can see above.

Then we just return our `CustomDatabaseSessionHandler` in the closure.

**Creating the actual CustomDatabaseSessionHandler**

Now that we're ready to fire off the new CustomDatabaseSessionHandler let's create it.

There is not much to do. Only four methods use the hardcoded columns. We will just extend the `Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler` class and overwrite those four.

```
<?php namespace MyProject\Extension;

use Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler;

class CustomDatabaseSessionHandler extends DatabaseSessionHandler {

    public function read($sessionId)
    {
        // Reading the session
    }

    public function write($sessionId, $data)
    {
        // Writing the session
    }

    public function destroy($sessionId)
    {
        // Destryoing the Session
    }

    public function gc($lifetime)
    {
        // Cleaning up expired sessions
    }

}
```

Since you want to only change column names you can even copy the method bodies from the parent class and just change what you want.

That's it. Happy coding and have fun with Laravel!

Comment: What changes do I have to make in my *app/config/session.php* file? I assume the `'driver'` should be set to `database`. Do I have to specify the `'connection'`?

Comment: Yes you do :) it should be set to a connection type defined in your app/config/database.php for example: mysql

Comment: It seems to work, the only problem I had, was with the primary key. The `DatabaseSessionHandler` uses this line `$session = $this->getQuery()->find($sessionId);` on `read`, and try to find the `id` field name which it's different in my table. I changed it to this `$session = $this->getQuery()->where('sesskey',$sessionId)->first();`
, do you know a better or more elegant way?

Comment: I think your way to do it is perfectly fine. Since the `id` column is hardcoded into the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class you'll probably have a hard time changing it. You would have to extend the `Builder` class for your purpose which would just be an overkill.

Comment: Thx Thomas Just a notice for all who are in the same situation, **`session.id` column should be 40 characters length**.

Answer (score 1):

When implementing, make sure you are locking the session as this is often forgotten and leads to unreliable session modifications. For more information read:

http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/10/symfony2-memcache-session-locking/

Answer (score -1):

You are able to use `SessionHandlerInterface`

```
class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface {    

// implememntation

}
$handler = new MySessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler($handler, true);
session_start();
```

#### References

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php